# Im coding my orm.js and when i run it, it gives me ```TypeError: connection.query is not a function```

Tags: javascript, node.js, express, model-view-controller, orm

Heres the code I have in my **orm.js** file

```js
// Import MySQL connection.
var connection = require("../config/connection.js");

   
function printQuestionMarks(num) {
  var arr = [];

  for (var i = 0; i < num; i++) {
    arr.push("?");
  }

  return arr.toString();
}

// Helper function to convert object key/value pairs to SQL syntax
function objToSql(ob) {
  var arr = [];

  // loop through the keys and push the key/value as a string int arr
  for (var key in ob) {
    var value = ob[key];
    // check to skip hidden properties
    if (Object.hasOwnProperty.call(ob, key)) {
      // if string with spaces, add quotations (Lana Del Grey => 'Lana Del Grey')
      if (typeof value === "string" && value.indexOf(" ") >= 0) {
        value = "'" + value + "'";
      }
      // e.g. {name: 'Lana Del Grey'} => ["name='Lana Del Grey'"]
      // e.g. {sleepy: true} => ["sleepy=true"]
      arr.push(key + "=" + value);
    }
  }

  // translate array of strings to a single comma-separated string
  return arr.toString();
}

// Object for all our SQL statement functions.
var orm = {
  all: function(tableInput, callback) {
    var queryString = "SELECT * FROM " + tableInput + ";";
    connection.query(queryString, function(err, result) {
      if (err) {
        throw err;
      }
      callback(result);
    });
  },
  create: function(table, cols, vals, callback) {
    var queryString = "INSERT INTO " + table;

    queryString += " (";
    queryString += cols.toString();
    queryString += ") ";
    queryString += "VALUES (";
    queryString += printQuestionMarks(vals.length);
    queryString += ") ";

    console.log(queryString);

    connection.query(queryString, vals, function(err, result) {
      if (err) {
        throw err;
      }

      callback(result);
    });
  },
  // An example of objColVals would be {name: panther, sleepy: true}
  update: function(table, objColVals, condition, callback) {
    var queryString = "UPDATE " + table;

    queryString += " SET ";
    queryString += objToSql(objColVals);
    queryString += " WHERE ";
    queryString += condition;

    console.log(queryString);
    connection.query(queryString, function(err, result) {
      if (err) {
        throw err;
      }

      callback(result);
    });
  },
  delete: function(table, condition, callback) {
    var queryString = "DELETE FROM " + table;
    queryString += " WHERE ";
    queryString += condition;

    connection.query(queryString, function(err, result) {
      if (err) {
        throw err;
      }

      callback(result);
    });
  }
};

// Export the orm object for the model (cat.js).
module.exports = orm;
```

The error displayed on the browser is:

```html
TypeError: connection.query is not a function
    at Object.all (/Users/tilesmaster/Desktop/burger/app/config/orm.js:46:16)
    at Object.all (/Users/tilesmaster/Desktop/burger/app/model/burgerModel.js:6:9)
    at /Users/tilesmaster/Desktop/burger/app/routes/api-routes.js:10:10
    at Layer.handle [as handle_request] (/Users/tilesmaster/Desktop/burger/node_modules/express/lib/router/layer.js:95:5)
    at next (/Users/tilesmaster/Desktop/burger/node_modules/express/lib/router/route.js:137:13)
    at Route.dispatch (/Users/tilesmaster/Desktop/burger/node_modules/express/lib/router/route.js:112:3)
    at Layer.handle [as handle_request] (/Users/tilesmaster/Desktop/burger/node_modules/express/lib/router/layer.js:95:5)
    at /Users/tilesmaster/Desktop/burger/node_modules/express/lib/router/index.js:281:22
    at Function.process_params (/Users/tilesmaster/Desktop/burger/node_modules/express/lib/router/index.js:335:12)
    at next (/Users/tilesmaster/Desktop/burger/node_modules/express/lib/router/index.js:275:10)
```

The error appears to be in the connection.query line I dont know why because I have the same exact code working in my other app.  This is pretty much the same code just different table name in my set-up MySQL database.

Its weird that, the other file worked and this is not working and giving me error.  Am I doing anything wrong syntsax wise? OR am I missing some npm packages? OR am I just linking each module.exports incorrectly? Please help in debug - thank you

THANKS IN ADVANCE!!!

Comment: You'll need to include the code in your `connection.js` file - the problem is somewhere in there. It's most likely a failure to get a database connection - incorrect credentials? incorrect host name? - but we don't have any information about that in your question.

Comment: how do you know this @Kryten cause your input directed me to the problem.  You helped me fix this error.  But I want to know how you were able to connect the issue to my connection.js file?

Comment: Your `connection` object *should* have a `query` property but it doesn't - that's what your error message is telling us. Your `connection` object is imported from `connection.js` - this means that somewhere in your `connection.js` file should be code that creates that `query` property. I don't know what it looks like, since we don't have that code in your question. So I made a guess, based on a rule of thumb: **when a connection to a server is not working, the first thing to check is the connection parameters: credentials, host name, port, etc.**

Comment: Thanks for the request, but I'm not able to serve as a mentor in any formal capacity. Keep asking questions here on SO and review some of the help pages, like [How do I ask a good question?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) - it includes some links to helpful pages.